# socket io client lost conection when server restarts

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, server, socket.io

so I am creating a module for the members that are using my services (cloudlist.xyz).

basically, we have a voting system in our service, this module is making a connection using socket io on the server and socket io client on the module, announcing to the user when someone votes on it

Everything is working normally, but when I restart the server to do some maintenance, all users are disconnected from socket io even when the server is on again

**Server side code :**

```
     var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
        console.log("Your app is listening on port " + server.address().port)
        }); 

        var io = require('socket.io')(server)
    io.on("connection",function(socket) {
  console.log("Someone Joined to our server api!")
})  

    //that's the part that he emits the event when someone votes

  io.of(`vote/${bot}`).emit("voted", user_votes.val());
```

**Module/client side:**

```
var https = require('https');
const { EventEmitter } = require("events");
var fetch = require('node-fetch')
const io = require("socket.io-client");


module.exports = class Cloud_client extends EventEmitter {
   constructor(id, token) {
      super();

      if (!id) throw new Error("Missing client instance on contructor");
      if (!token) throw new Error("Missing token on constructor");

      this.id = id;
      this.token = token;
      this.socket = io.connect(`https://www.cloudlist.xyz/vote/${id}`, {
         reconnect:true,
         autoConnect:true,
         reconnectionDelay: 1000,
         reconnectionDelayMax : 5000,
         reconnectionAttempts: Infinity      
      });
      this.socket.on("connect", () => this.emit("connected"));
      this.socket.on("disconnect", (...args) => {this.socket.open();

      });
      this.socket.on("voted", (...args) => this.emit("voted", ...args));
  };
```

**this is an example of someone using the module:**

```
var cdl = require("cloud-list") 
var cloud_client = new cdl("701456902160121966","5669556617e2a070ada1688") 

cloud_client.on("connected", (data) => { 
console.log(`Connected to the api Server`)
})  

cloud_client.on("voted", (data) => { 
console.log(`Thanks,user ${data.user_name} for voting on us :)`)
})
```

When I connect to the server, it sends the message of this example saying "Connected to the api Server", but when I restart the server, I don't receive anything. Already tried             `this.socket.on("disconnect", (...args) => {this.socket.open()});` or  `this.socket.on("disconnect", (...args) => {this.socket.connect()});` ,but still the same thing,user can't reconnect again.
**the only way for users to connect again is to restart his project, which is very bad**

Answer (score 0):

Socket connections require the server to be serving. Socket.io doesn't seem good for a voting system unless you want it to be real time. It's expected for clients to restart when the server restarts.

Answer (score 0):

As per with working in Socket server we need to restart our node socket server during the restart of the main servers like apache or Nginx.

Because it is not an automatic process on the server.